# Upload Multiple Files With Ktor

Tags: kotlin, multipart, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, ktor-client

I am Using ktor with kmm to upload a list of images to server
But there is no available guide in the docs to make me upload list of files
i am converting my files to byte array and uploading them

I tried to upload it this way

```
mainClient.post {
    setBody(
        MultiPartFormDataContent(
              formData {
append("attachments[]", listOf(toBytes(kmmFile),toBytes(kmmFile)) )
             }
          )
     )
}
```

but got connection refused

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all byte arrays in a collection and call the `append` method for each of them. Here is an example:

```
val images: List<ByteArray> // assigned externally
val response = client.post("https://httpbin.org/post") {
    setBody(MultiPartFormDataContent(
        formData {
            for (bytes in images) {
                append("attachments[]", bytes)
            }
        }
    ))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use below code for uploading single file and run forEach when call this method(for each n append doesn't work for me). I think your serve must be  supported upload multiple file at same time.

```
    override suspend fun upload(
    uploadFiles: Map<String, File>,
    texts: Map<String, String>
): ResultWrapper<ResponseData<List<UploadFileDto>>> {

    return {
        httpClient.submitForm {
            url(BASE_URL + "api/v1/static/upload-file")
            method = HttpMethod.Post
            setBody(MultiPartFormDataContent(
                formData {
                    headers {
                        append(
                            "document",
                            uploadFiles.entries.first().value.readBytes(),
                            Headers.build {
                                append(
                                    HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition,
                                    "filename=${uploadFiles.entries.first().value.name}"
                                )
                            })
                    }
                }
            ))
        }.body()
    }
```